# Send keywords and targeting info to AdMob for better ads

Tags: android, admob, keyword, ads, targeting

On admob, when I click on **Monetize** > **AdMob Network report** and then select "**Targeting Type**" in the drop-down selection (at the bottom left of the page), I see five lines:

```
- (Unmatched ad requests)
- (unknown)
- Contextual
- Interest-based
- Placement
```

Can someone explain me how such results are possible as I am in an **Android App** and no targeting information is provided to Google (for me, **contextual** is linked to the environnement of the user in the app like, the text on a webpage for a web-site visitor for example...)

Actually I would like to **improve my ECPM by providing keywords and -if useful- user (non-personal) info to Admob** as I do not do it yet.

Does anymone have any idea how this could be achieved and how Admob can currently propose keyword-based advertising when I do not provide anything to it? This is a mystery for me :-)

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Answer (score 9):

You can provide keywords to admob so the ads can be targeted. You do this by using the addKeyword function when you create a request. Like this:

```
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("an id for your device")
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addKeyword("orange")
        .addKeyword("yellow")
        .addKeyword("blue");
```

This method is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html

There you can find other methods to provide information to AdMob: gender, location, birthday...

Here's more information as well: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you already try this and does it work ? I mean do you see a difference with the ads. Are they actually targeted on this info ?

Comment: I haven't really checked. I have all my devices marked as "test devices" so I don't really see the ads. In any case this is the way to do this and after that is up-to Google to do its magic.